# Regex to get an interval with a '/'

Tags: java, regex

I have this `Descriptions`

| Description |
| --- |
| T2 SMD MOS N/P SI1555 SOT363 700/600mA 20/8V -55/150C Dual 390/850mOHM |
| T2 SMD MOS N/P FDS8858CZ SO-8 8.6/7.3A 30V 0.017OHM |
| T2 SMD MOS N/P EM6M2T2R SOT563 200/200mA 20V 1OHM ESD PROT |
| FLTR SMD 0603 FER BEAD 220OHM @100MHZ +/-25% 0,4OHM 1.4A |

What I want to return is:

| Current |
| --- |
| 700/600mA |
| 8.6/7.3A |
| 200/200mA |
| 1.4A |

For that I tried this regex

`(\s|^)(-)?(\d+\.?\d*(A|mA)(DC|AC)?)(?=\s|$)`

I could not get it to work with values containing a `/` as `700/600mA` , `8.6/7.3A` , `200/200mA`

How could I correct my regex?

Comment: Try `(?:-?\b\d*\.?\d+/)?(?<![^\s/])-?\d*\.?\d+m?A(?:[DA]C)?(?!\S)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
(?<!\S)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?m?A(?:[DA]C)?(?!\S)
```

**Explanation**

- `(?<!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the left
- `-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `(?:/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?` Optionally match `/` and 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `m?A` Match an optional `m` followed by `A`
- `(?:[DA]C)?` Match optional `DA` or `AC`
- `(?!\S)` Assert a whitespace boundary to the right

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/xaNnTM/1)

If you meant to match `m` `mA` `DC` `AC` the optional group should be part of the alternation:

```
 (?<!\S)-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?(?:/-?\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?:m?A|[DA]C)(?!\S)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oBac5y/1)

Comment: it's working as wanted but when i try 700/6,5mA it returns me 5mA , for this case i want my regex to return nothing . thanks in advance

Comment: @Benkhelifaamine I have updateed the pattern

Comment: `m?A([DA]C)?` is too loose. It captures `200/200ADC` and `200/200AAC` and `200/200mAAC`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus It is in the OP's pattern.

Comment: @Thefourthbird If their pattern if perfect then they wouldn't be asking for help =)

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Sounds reasonable, I have added another pattern with an alternation to provide for that.

Answer (score -1):

You could use

```
([\d./]{2,}m*A+)
```

if you don't need to catch all matches in the same pattern

Answer (score -1):

```
(\d+(\.\d+)?\/)?\d+(\.\d+)?[m]?A
```

Comment: Please read [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). While this code block may answer the OP's question, this answer would be much more useful if you explain how this code is different from the code in the question, what you've changed, why you've changed it and why that solves the problem without introducing others. - [From Review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/32238228)